# Map values to class properties dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, xml, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

this is my scenario:
I have an application that downloads xml files and extracts data from them. To achieve this I've created a xml configuration file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<labelsSets>
    <labelsSet getUrl="https://www.address.com/services/rest/product-display.xml?expand_entities=0&amp;limit=100000000">
        <fields>
            <field name="item" required="true" xPath="result/item" doGet="false" isRoot="true" />
            <field name="Title" required="true" xPath="title" doGet="false" />
        </fields>
    </labelsSet>
</labelsSets>
```

Where the "field" nodes are the values that I have to extract from the downloaded xml.
So, I have to insert the data into a database and I generated class like this with EF DbContext Generator:

```
[Table("Winery")]
public partial class Winery
{
    public Winery()
    {
        Wine = new HashSet<Wine>();
    }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Wine> Wine { get; set; }
}
```

**Is there a way to map the extracted values from xml to db table class?**

I thought to add "table" and "tableField" attributes to "field" node in configuration, but I cannot find the way to achieve the mapping between the extracted values and db classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //alternate method
            //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LabelsSets));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            LabelsSets labelSets = (LabelsSets)xs.Deserialize(reader);


        }
    }

}
[XmlRoot("labelsSets")]
public class LabelsSets
{
    [XmlElement("labelsSet")]
    public List<LabelsSet> labelSet {get;set;}
}

[XmlRoot("labelsSet")]
public class LabelsSet
{
    [XmlAttribute("getUrl")]
    public string getUrl {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("fields")]
    public Fields fields {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("fields")]
public class Fields
{
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public List<Field> fields {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("field")]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("required")]
    public Boolean required {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("xPath")]
    public string xPath {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("doGet")]
    public Boolean doGet {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("isRoot")]
    public Boolean isRoot {get;set;}
}
```